# string min,max length function

Tags: php, strlen

I'm trying to check min and max length of strings:

If I pass it an array, such as follows, I want the values to be returned if true and NULL if false:

```
$lenghts = array('a' => array('min' => 20, 'max' => 70),
                 'b' => array('min' => 50, 'max' => 800),
                 'c' => array('min' => 3,  'max' =>8));
```

And the values are:

```
$values = array('thread_title' => 'this is it', 'thread_content' => 'this is not it', 'thread_tags' => 'also not it')
```

;

**EDIT**

It's like 5am here (really quite sleepy), I should copied and pasted the correct version, sorry:

```
function string_min_max($string_array, $array)
{
   $returns = array();  # store returned values
   foreach ($array as $key)
   {
      #  check for minimum:
      if (array_key_exists('min', $key))
      {
         $minimum = (strlen($string_array[$key]) < $key['min'] ? $key = NULL : $key);
      }

      if (array_key_exists('max', $key))
      {
         $maximum = (strlen($string_array($key)) > $key['max'] ? $key = NULL : $key);
      }

      if ($minimum !== NULL && $maximum !== NULL)
      {
         $returns[$key]['min'] = $minimum;
         $returns[$key]['max'] = $maximum; 
      }
   }
}
```

This does not work:

```
   string_min_max($values, $lengths);
```

Comment: "WOuld something like this work?" I don't know, does it work? It's your code, you tell us. If it doesn't work as expected, tell us what is wrong with it.

Comment: I see a set of min and max string lengths - I don't, however, see what strings you're trying to check the length of

Comment: Are you saying you'd call your function with "string_min_max($lengths)"?  Also you mention $returns to store returned values, but then only assign things to $minimum.  Please double check what you've got posted to make sure its  trying to do what you think.

Comment: you are comparing (array and value.) $key < $key['min'] ....???

Answer (score 0):

This code is reducable to:

```
function string_min_max($array)
{
   $returns = array();  # store returned values
   foreach ($array as $key)
   {
      #  check for minimum:
      if (TRUE)
      {
         $minimum = (FALSE ? $key = NULL : $key);
      }
   }
}
```

OR:

```
function string_min_max($array)
{
   $returns = array();  # store returned values
   foreach ($array as $key)
   {
      $minimum = $key;
   }
}
```

OR:

```
function string_min_max($array)
{
   $returns = array();  # store returned values
}
```

OR:

```
(void)
```

So the answer is: no. It won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking too much at the details, one obvious problem is that you are not returning anyting from your function; you are building an array but you don´t use it so it gets destroyed at the moment your function ends.

I think that at least you will need this at the end of your function:

```
  return $returns;
}         // end function
```

You can then call your function like:

```
$results = string_min_max($values, $lenghts);
```

Answer (score 0):

if use this for validate string by length and chars :

```
function checkString($string, $regex, $minlenght = 3, $maxlenght = 20) {
        if(preg_match($regex, $string) && strlen($string) >= $minlenght && strlen($string) <= $maxlenght) return true;
        return false;
}
```